# How to pass QString variable to QFile?

Tags: qt, qstring, qfile

getData gets the chosen file from a QTreeView and displays it on label 'test', enables the 'Apply' button, which when clicked calls setTheme

```
void OptionsDialog::getData(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QString selected = model2->filePath(index);
    ui->test->setText(selected);
    ui->pushButton_apply_theme->setEnabled(true);
}

void OptionsDialog::setTheme()
{
    //char *file = selected->toLatin1().data();
    //const std::string file = selected->toStdString();
    QFile qss(selected);
    qss.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    qApp->setStyleSheet(qss.readAll());
    qss.close();
}
```

I can't seem to pass the filePath to QFile in the format it wants, commented lines are some attempts which failed. ' char *file = selected->toLatin1().data();' compiles but segfaults in use.

As is it fails with:

```
qt/optionsdialog.cpp: In member function ‘void OptionsDialog::setTheme()’:
qt/optionsdialog.cpp:176:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘QFile::QFile(QString*&)’
     QFile qss(selected);
```

Forgive me for I am used to python, this is driving me nuts, any help appreciated!

Comment: You seem to have declared `selected` as a pointer. I don't think there is a reason to do so in this case.

Comment: That's bad grammar in English.  One asks: "How DO YOU pass A QString variable to A QFile?"  (The corrections are capitalized.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QString selected = model2->filePath(index);` does not set the variable in the (maybe same named) member `OptionsDialog::selected`. This creates a new local variable.

If you have a member variable called `selected` then you should use it like this:

```
void OptionsDialog::getData(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    selected = model2->filePath(index);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, got rid of the 'QString' bit and changed the declaration from 'QString *selected' to 'QString selected' in the header file and it now works perfectly, thanks! :)